# How can you change the default string length (varchar) of all created columns?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When you create a migration in rails and specify strings the column length is, by default, 255. Is there a way to set all columns created that don't specify a length, to default to some other number?

Generally speaking 255 is fine, but in my situation I need to switch the encoding on string columns to utf8mb4 and when I do this indexes break as the index can't be longer than 767 bytes:

`Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

As utf8 is stored as 3 bytes so `3 * 255 = 765`, but utf8mb4 is 4 bytes so `4 * 255 = 1020`, which will fail.

So once I change the `database.yml` to use `utf8mb4` encoding, when I reload the schema things fail when they try to load the indexes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to force Rails to use a length of 191 for varchar columns.  First, create an initializer where you will override the default varchar length. I created mine in `config/initializers/schema_string_limit.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:string] = {
  name: 'varchar',
  limit: 191
}
```

Now recreate your database and run all the migrations:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Make sure you use `rake db:migrate` and not `rake db:schema:load`. We need to force Rails to run all the migrations again because the existing `schema.rb` already reflects the 255 size. Once you've run through the migrations with the new defaults you'll have a new `schema.rb` that uses a length of 191 so you'll be able to simply load the schema from then on.

Comment: Awesome, I knew it had to be something simple like that, just didn't know where to look. Thank you!

Comment: This solution throws the following error: `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter (NameError)`. Putting `require 'active_record'` in front of it or downgrading the `mysql2` gem didn't change anything. `Rails 5.2.1`, `ruby 2.5.0p0`.

Comment: To fix it, put `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb'` in the first line of the initializer.

Comment: The length issue has been solved. You simply need to upgrade your version of MySQL to 5.7.9 or the version of MariaDB to 10.2.2, at least, to support utf8mb4 character set and 3072 bytes key length with InnoDB. In Rails, support for this has been merged, see: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33608

Answer (score 4):

You can do two things:

1. you can limit your index, so it will check only the first X chars:

   `add_index(:name1, :name2, length: 250)`
2. change all string with different limit

   `change_column :table1, :name1, :string, :limit => 250`

   `change_column :table1, :name2, :string, :limit => 250`

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the limiting index thing, that's pretty handy, but @infused 's answer was what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in the migration file is very easy.

```
create_table :articles do |t|
 t.string :title, :null => false
 t.text :details, :limit => 3000, :null => false
end
```

Comment: Yea, but I'd rather not go an edit past migrations, as that's generally bad practice.

Comment: As it turns out, the limit can (now) be specified in the command line:

rails generate model user pseudo:string{30}
Source: usage doc from Rails GitHub project

Setting the default, however, still appears to require editing the migration manually.

For additional migration options, see the official Rails migrations guide.